# Sharing owin identity cookie with MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, single-sign-on, owin, shared

I´m doing SSO App with user management in MVC 5, but I can't share the cookie between apps for example

http ://SSO
http ://app

different sites in IIS, I think this is something like cross domain, so in the app2 when I have something like this in the startup.auth

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieName = "sharedcookie",
            CookieDomain = "SSO",
            CookieHttpOnly = false,
            
            //CookieDomain = "localhost",
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE:**
thanks to Chris Pratt for the answer  that there is no way to do this which leads me to another question that is
can I share a cookie between

```
name1.domain.com/app1 and 
name2.domain.com/app2
```

With OWIN?

Comment: Are the apps at completely different domains, not just different subdomains on the same domain? If you're dealing with subdomains, you can have the cookie be set on the domain and then it will be shared with all subdomains of that domain. However, if you have completely different domains, there is 100% no possible way to share the cookie. Period. Cookies are domain-bound.

Comment: so my single sign on must be on the same domain but can have diferent subdomain. Tnks!!!

Comment: can i share a cookie like this name.domain.com/app1 and name2.domain.com/app2 ?

Comment: Yes. However, you will also need to ensure that the machine keys for all the sites are the same or although the site receives the cookie, it still won't be able to understand it. More information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755177%28v=ws.10%29.aspx. It's possible to do SSO with multiple different domains, but it's *much* more complex.

Comment: If the cookie is set on *.domain.com, then all subdomains will get that cookie (sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, etc.). The path afterwards is not taken into account. However, like I said, simply receiving the cookie is not always enough. If there's something in the cookie like an encrypted session id, then a cookie set by Site A would be essentially garbage to Site B, unless they employ the same encryption schemes. That's where machine keys come in.

Comment: tanks again!!! please answer the question so i can mark it as OK

Comment: in doing this I am no longer able to log the user out, any suggestions for that?

Comment: @BlackICE: Little late, but somehow I never noticed your comment before. They key is to invalidate the security stamp first before logging the user out. You can do this via `await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this article on code project today when I was wondering the same thing, not 100% sure but definitely seems possible to me.

Part 1 - The design:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Part 2 - The implementation:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114484/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-appl

Granted this is not actually sharing a cookie between domains but using a SSO user management web service (which seems fine to me!)

NB: I know link only answers are discouraged but these articles are huge, anyone who wants to tell me how to do this properly is welcome :)